# You can't change configuration 'gwtBuild' because it is already resolved?

Tags: gwt, gradle

I have set up a multi folder project with build.gradle file as shown in https://github.com/Catalysts/catalysts-gradle-plugins/wiki/cat-gwt ,here is /baseDir/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'cat-gwt'

dependencies {
    gwtBuild (
        [project(path: ':proj1', configuration: 'gwtCompile')]
    )
}

subprojects {
    // apply plugin: 'xxx'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
        }
    }
}

gwt {
    modules {
        projectX {
            modulename = 'cc.catalysts.gwt.example.projectX'
        }
    }
}
```

but while running the gradle build I get the following error.

D:\Spring3HibernateApp>gradle build

```
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:classes UP-TO-DATE
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:jar UP-TO-DATE
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:test UP-TO-DATE
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:check UP-TO-DATE
:catalysts-gradle-plugins:build UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'D:\Spring3HibernateApp\build.gradle' line: 5

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Spring3HibernateApp'.

You can't change configuration 'gwtBuild' because it is already resolved!
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.901 secs
```

please help :(

Comment: I am not sure if this is the cause of the exception. but in your dependencies your subproject is named `proj1` and in the last part, where you define your modules, it is named `projectX`. Those names has to be the same.

Comment: thanks friend but seems its not the solution,it didnt .